# Magento 2 : Order confirmation email cron language picks up default language

Tags: magento2, order-email, cronjobs, multi-language

- I have multi language site.
- Created a cron job to send order confirmation email.
- I have created an email template for specific language.
- The problem is, shipping and billing country is displaying in default language instead of order's store language.

How to fix this issue? I need to display the countries in specific order's store language.